# Trying to create a dice in Processing but clicking is not triggering it

Tags: java, processing

I want to make a program that would show the face of a die after you click in the rectangle that says "Roll" but when I click, nothing happens.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;

public Random random = new Random();

public color purple = #B507F5;
public int diceChoose = random.nextInt(6);
public int x = mouseX;
public int y = mouseY;


public void setup() {
  size(750, 900);
  background(255);

}

public void draw() {
  strokeWeight(3);

  //dice roll button
  rect(100, 700, 550, 150);
  textSize(100);
  fill(purple);
  text("Roll", 280, 815);
  noFill();

  //dice face
  rect(100, 100, 550, 550);

  roll();
}

public void one() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(375, 375, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void two() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(525, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 525, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void three() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(375, 375, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 525, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void four() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(525, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 225, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void five() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(375, 375, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 225, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void six() {
  fill(0);
  ellipse(525, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 525, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 225, 100, 100);
  ellipse(525, 375, 100, 100);
  ellipse(225, 375, 100, 100);
  noFill();
}

public void roll() {
  if (mousePressed && x > 100 && x < 650 && y > 700 && y < 850) {
    diceChoose = random.nextInt(6);
    if (diceChoose == 0) {
      one();
    }
    else if (diceChoose == 1) {
      two();
    }
    else if (diceChoose == 2) {
      three();
    }
    else if (diceChoose == 3) {
      four();
    }
    else if (diceChoose == 4) {
      five();
    }
    else if (diceChoose == 5) {
      six();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that something is slightly wrong in it?

Comment: I didn't realize I could edit the post before I posted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `x` and `y` variables equal to `mouseX` and `mouseY` at the very beginning of the program. But that does **not** mean that when `mouseX` or `mouseY` change, your `x` and `y` variables will change too. Consider this:

```
float x = 100;
float y = x;
x = 200;
println(y); //prints 100!
```

So instead of referring to `x` and `y` (which never change), you need to use `mouseX` and `mouseY` in this if statement:

```
  if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 650 && mouseY > 700 && mouseY < 850) {
```

Then you have some other issues (you don't actually detect a click), but this is the answer to your first question.

By the way, the way I figured this out was by simply adding `println()` statements. I put one before your if statement and one inside of it:

```
  println("here 1");
  if (x > 100 && x < 650 && y > 700 && y < 850) {
    println("here 2");
```

The "here 1" printed out, but the "here 2" did not, so I knew to look closer at the logic in your if statements. In the future, you might try this type of debugging yourself, save yourself the trouble of making a post!